# Does a Venn diagram need a Universal set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In my book there are questions where there are two intersecting sets $A$ and $B$ and the questions begin by saying something like "In the given Venn diagram ... ". But there is no Universal set surrounding the two sets $A$ and $B$. Just the two sets themselves. Strictly speaking is this kind of diagram an Euler diagram or a Venn diagram ? Does a Venn diagram need a Universal set ?

Comment: There's an implied, unspecified universal set, but for all you know, it's just $A \cup B$. In any case, if you're not interested in points outside of $A \cup B$, there's no need to show an enclosing box.

Comment: take the book page as Universal set (ha ha)

Comment: It's implied if not present. A Venn diagram is more general than an Euler diagram because the presence of an overlap between set representations does not implies the existence of elements in that overlap.

Comment: As a somewhat different way of looking at it, some relations between sets (union, intersection, difference) do not require a universal set, while others (compliment) do. You can use Venn/Euler diagrams to represent the former, which doesn't require you to specify a universal set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction between an Euler diagram and a Venn diagram is not the presence or absence of a universal set, but in the relations that are represented.  In a Venn diagram, every possible intersection is shown, even if one or more of those intersections is empty.  In an Euler diagram, only "interesting" (i.e. nonempty) intersections are shown.  For example ([blatantly stolen from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram)):

A Venn diagram:

[image]

An Euler diagram showing the same information:

[image]

Comment: But if the Universal set isn't specified there is one possibility not represented, i.e. the complement of the union of the sets that are specified.

Comment: In that case the universal set is the union of the sets shown.  In a Venn diagram, this follows from the fact that every possible intersection is shown.  In an Euler diagram, this follows from the fact that only non-empty sets are shown, hence the complement is empty.